# Having difficulty with re-installing R in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

Very recently I shifted to Ubuntu from Windows and downloaded R-base (3.4.4) and R studio. However, some packages (car, ROCR etc) were not available and hence I tried to update R. Because of error messages, I finally tried to uninstall and remove R and then install it again.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install r-base
```

However, it is showing me error message like,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.2.20200221-1~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So basically right now, I have no R-base installed.

I tried to remove R-base.

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base
```

And all I am getting is-

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'r-base' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am a beginner in both R and Linux. I need your valuable suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe add `r-recommended`? `sudo apt install r-base r-recommended`

Comment: It is not happening either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04, please follow these steps if you are using your local machine of your own. (If your are working in any office environment please setup proxy and follow these steps)

1) Let’s first add the relevant GPG key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

2) Add the R Repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
```

3) Update Package Lists

```
sudo apt update
```

4)  Install R

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

5) Test Install

```
sudo -i R
```

6) Installing R Packages from CRAN

```
install.packages('dplyr')
```

Comment: All I am getting is- The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.0-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.0-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @RUPSABASAK Could you please try to install R 4.0.0 and try once, as Ubuntu is recommending the same. https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/